# Making tooltip texts on wxpython Ribbon control

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, ribbon-control

I'm trying to create tooltip texts for a ribbon control. I have set the help_strings but don't know how to display them. Even if it is just a tooltip text as wxpython displays for a button would be fine for me.

I have attached the code sample (a modified version of the RibbobDemo.py) on which I would like to have the help_strings on mouseover.

I appreciate code examples or pointing references.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.ribbon as RB

class RibbonFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="", pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size, style)

        self._ribbon = RB.RibbonBar(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        home = RB.RibbonPage(self._ribbon, wx.ID_ANY, "Examples", wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_FILE_OPEN))
        toolbar_panel = RB.RibbonPanel(home, wx.ID_ANY, "Toolbar", wx.NullBitmap, wx.DefaultPosition,
                                   wx.DefaultSize, RB.RIBBON_PANEL_NO_AUTO_MINIMISE)

        toolbar = RB.RibbonToolBar(toolbar_panel, wx.ID_ANY)
        # this is just a simple tool
        toolbar.AddTool(wx.ID_ANY,  wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_FILE_OPEN), help_string=" the first tool")
        toolbar.AddTool(wx.ID_ANY, wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_ERROR), help_string=" the second tool")
        toolbar.AddTool(wx.ID_ANY, wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_INFORMATION), help_string=" the third tool")
        toolbar.AddSeparator()



        self._ribbon.Realize()

        self._logwindow = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,
                                  wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_LEFT | wx.TE_BESTWRAP | wx.BORDER_NONE)

        s = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        s.Add(self._ribbon, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        s.Add(self._logwindow, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(s)




if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = RibbonFrame(None, -1, "wxPython Ribbon Sample Application", size=(800, 600))
    frame.CenterOnScreen()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got **wxPython3.0 Docs and Demos** installed from http://www.wxpython.org/download.php. In that, under the Advanced Generic Widgets, I found the demo for Pure-Python RibbonBar which has a tooltip text display. It displays as a usual button tooltip. However, I decided to satisfy myself by that. I thank everyone involved in compiling the docs and demos. It will be very very useful!